# Realtime database doesn't work on firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in Android app development and making an application on Android Studio.

Can check the user list from Authentication tab on firebase after I made an account, but Realtime Database doesn't work and can't get any data.

Here is my `Registration Activity` file's realtime database part code.
Please let me know what the problem is.

```
mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
        final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        final String name = mName.getText().toString();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener((Executor) getApplication(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "로그인 실패!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference currentUserDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);

                    Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                    userInfo.put("email", email);
                    userInfo.put("name", name);
                    userInfo.put("profileImageUrl", "default");

                    currentUserDB.updateChildren(userInfo);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The database:

[image]

Comment: **realtime database doesn't work and can't get any database** Can you please elaborate clearly what do you want?

Comment: Please post your database rules so we can check if you have allowed user to write

Comment: @Ashish Is that what you mean? => {
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}

Comment: yes i am talking about them have you set your rules ?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I belived that I could see the added user lists on realtime database tab as soos as I registered an account on Android App but I couldn't.

Comment: @Ashish No, do i have to something for rules?

Comment: @melpark what you mean you see added on realtime database ?

Comment: Check the logcat output when the `updateChildren` executes for any relevant messages. If those messages don't make sense to you, include them in your question (there's an edit link right under it) so we can help.